# "What this value exactly equal to?"

Tags: c

How this result divided by which number?

Here's my problem

```
average=sum/(i-1);
```

`average=sum/?` the (i-1) should be equal =?

THE FULL CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int maxInput = 5;
    int i;
    double number, average, sum=0.0;

    for(i=1; i<=maxInput; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d. Enter a number: ", i);
        scanf("%lf",&number);
        if(number < 0.0)
            goto jump;
        sum += number;
    }
    jump:
    average=sum/(i-1);
    printf("Sum = %.2f\n", sum);
    printf("Average = %.2f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on `number`, since if that is negative, it `goto`'s out of the loop, so the value of `i` is the last value it had. Otherwise it will be equal to `maxInput`. You should learn to use a debugger to step through your program and see the value of each variable.

Comment: The loop is valid while `i <= maxInput`. When the loop is ended (if not left by the goto), the value will be `i = maxInput + 1` which is the value used for the average expression. Was the question about this?

Answer (score 1):

`average=sum/(i-1)` is correct, since the value of `i` at the start of the loop is `1`.

If the initial value of `i` is changed to `0`, then the average would be
`average=sum/i`....but the condition of the loop would have to be changed to `i < maxInput`.